# Creating a Page to View the List of Posts for a Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

*(**Moderator's Note:** The original title was "viewing custom post types")*

I've setup a custom post type called `'recordings'` with a custom taxonomy called `'themes'`:

```
add_action('init', 'recordings');
function recordings() {
  $args = array(
    'label' => __('Recordings'),
    'singular_label' => __('Recordings'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields')
  );
  register_post_type( 'recordings' , $args );
}
register_taxonomy("Themes", array("recordings"), array(
  "hierarchical" => true, 
  "label" => "Themes", 
  "singular_label" => "Theme", 
  "rewrite" => true
));
```

I've read that I should now make a copy of `page.php`, rename it `recordings-page.php` and season to taste (code is as follows):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: recordingsPage
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="container">
  <div id="content" role="main">
  <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>
    <?php $recent = new WP_Query('post_type=recording&posts_per_page=10&meta_key=Date&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC'); ?>
    <?php while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
      <?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . 
        get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . 
        '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' 
      ); ?>
      <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 
          'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 
          'after' => '</div>' 
        ) ); ?>
        <?php edit_post_link( 
          __( 'Edit', 'twentyten' ), 
          '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' 
        ); ?>
      </div><!-- .entry-content -->
      <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #container -->
```

But this is where I'm stuck. I'm not sure how I should call my recordings-page?  I've added a new page called recordings, but all that shows up is the header/nav and the sidebar. I'm working with a fresh install using the TwenyTen theme. I'm sure I'm missing something here but I don't know what.

Comment: it doesn't look like my code for recordings-page.php showed up entirely. am I not formatting it correctly?

Comment: here's my recordings-page.php code:;

Comment: @don de lion - I reformatted for you. All likes of code must be indented 4 spaces to format correctly.

Comment: @don de lion: What do you want to do? Create an "archive page" for multiple recordings, using a "fake" page? Or a template for a single recording?

Comment: Is your code missing the s at the end of recording in the post_type query?

Comment: @Jan Fabry: Yes, I'd like to create an Archives page for different recordings (they're archival recordings, funnily enough). There will be many of them - around 30 - that I'd like to be able to sort by category/theme and tags.

Comment: @Christopher - that's what I thought (the s at the end of recording); I added an s, but nothing changes. I should clarify though: when I enter the custom post, and click view post, I see the page w/the post (it shows at localhost/prx/archives/recordings/recording-1). But if I just click the recordings link in the menu bar, I get a page showing the header, menu bar, and side bar only (address localhost/prx/recordings-1), and the side bar is shifted towards the center of the page by about the width of the sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be as simple as you needing to set the Page Template to *"recordingsPage"* as you can see in the following screenshots:

[image]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20110222-022323.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/Fullscreen-20110222-022436.png))</sub>

## UPDATE

Looking again at your code it seems you define your post type as plural (`'recordings'`) and 
 yet you refer to it as singular (`'recording'`) in your `WP_Query`. You need to be consistent; WordPress can't figure out the difference *(My experience says to go with singular all the way but if you have existing recordings in your database you'll now need to update those records to use 'recording'`instead of 'recordings'`.)*

Comment: Hi Mike, I did set the page template to recordingspage as well, but it didnt' change. I think I'm just not really calling the posts I've made? I guess I expect my custom post to be seen as a regular post, and I'm confused when I don't see it in the Recent posts section of the sidebar, for example. Apologies if this is too sophomoric; I get a little fuzzy when digging through the code (but working on improving that).

Comment: @don de lion - See my update.

Comment: okay I've made the change to recording on the post type, but it's still the same. .. I found a tutorial - http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/02/02/showing-custom-post-types-on-your-home-blog-page - and added the following code:
   

 add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

 if ( is_home() && false == $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] )
  $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'recordings'' ) );

 return $query;
}

Comment: heres the code: 
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

 if ( is_home() && false == $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] )
  $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'recordings', ) );

 return $query;
}

Comment: now all posts show up on home page: regular and custom. this is the right direction I'm thinking? The site's for showcasing a series of archival recordings on numerous topics, w/shared tags across many of the individual talks. Preferably, there'd be a page called, for example, seminars, w/excerpt posts in the main content area, along w/a 'browse categories' section in the sidebar & a custom search bar for searching by word/topic. I'll be reading the tut(s) mentioned above, but am I thinking this through proper? any and all comments greatly appreciated.

Comment: @don de lion - You should post any code as an update to your question, not in the comments since you can't format code properly in comments. Also, your *real* question seems to be spilling into the comments. It seems it might really help you to first ask what approach to take rather than how to fix the code above. I think it would really help to **[ask a new question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)** and explain what you are trying to accomplish *(as you partially have in your comments)*, list the approaches you've considered, and ask for recommendations.